# Universal iPhone and iPad Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ipad

I am creating a simple app and have begun this and its running a universal app so I have my normal files and folders and an folder called iPad, with a single xib file.

When I run this the splash screen work fine for both, but both iPad and iPhone go to the iPhone view controller, how can I get the iPad go to its own view controller.

This is because I want to present the app pages with in the iPad slightly different etc.

AM I right in sayign I need to create a .h and .m files for the iPad xib file and then assign this to these then it run's??

**EDIT ADDITIONAL**

I would like to create a split view application version for the iPad but rather than create two separate projects how can I change / create my iPad view into a spilt view? Are there any links to this for ease or is this quite simple?

In answer to this then I think not.

Many Thanks
Si

Comment: There's a nice box at the bottom of the page to put answers in - it also lets everyone else know that the question has been answered ;)

Comment: I cannot answer fro another 8 hours so will re-edit this when I can tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't work with universal applications (or split view) yet but I know most of what you are asking is covered in section 7 of the Stanford course [Developing Apps for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774?i=90218598).

Answer (score 0):

You can check device weather it will be iPad or iPhone by using below code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

#if (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200)
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) //ipad
{
    ipadiphoneflag=@"1"; // ipad
}
else
{
    ipadiphoneflag=@"0"; // iphone

}
#else // iphone
    ipadiphoneflag=@"0";
#endif  

//After you can call respective controller base on device

if([ipadiphoneflag intValue]==0)//Load view of iphone controller
{

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
else //Load view of iPad controller
{
    if(ipad_navigationcontroller==nil)
        ipad_navigationcontroller=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objipad];
    [self.ipad_navigationcontroller setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [window addSubview:ipad_navigationcontroller.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will look at this at a later date.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully i have answered my own question.

I created a .h and .m file then reassigned the iPad xib files class to the .h file and it seemed to work and load this view instead of the generic one.

As for the universal app with iPads split view I am still working on.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to use same code but different xib file, you just need to append "~ipad"

eg: 
myCustomView.xib     <--- iPhone

myCustomView~ipad.xib       <------ iPad